# Always the routing redirecting to home page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

My Angular App routing id always showing home page content only. The URL is remaining the same.

Example: When I try to go to `'/test'` page, only home page content is showing. Test page content is not showing.

Below is the code.
**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { ProductAlertsComponent } from './product-alerts/product-alerts.component';
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './product-details/product-details.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '../../node_modules/@angular/router';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    ProductAlertsComponent,
    ProductDetailsComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path:'products/:productId',component: ProductDetailsComponent },
      { path:'test',component: TestComponent },
      { path:'',component: ProductComponent},

    ])


  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have added router-outlet in app component also.

app.component.ts

```
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-product>

</app-product>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems that you are having `<app-product>  </app-product>`  in your `app.component.ts` file remove that

Comment: Whats the contents of `AppRoutingModule` that you importing before `RouterModule`? Try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `app-product` so your code instead of

```
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-product>

</app-product>
</div>
```

should be

```
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Also as @Dima specify you need to show the code for `AppRoutingModule` may be that is something causing the problem

[Here is basic routing example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example)